# Groovy: automatically extend all setters for properties

Tags: groovy

If I have a groovy class like this:

```
class WebSession{
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email
}
```

I want to be able to use the automatic setters to set the value.  For example:

```
WebSessionuser = new WebSession()
webSession.firstName = 'John'
```

But have the setter it calls do extra stuff, like log something or persist the object to cache.

How would I do this without having to define all the setters manually?  So far I have something like this, but I can't quite get it working:

```
    webSession.properties.each{ key, value ->
        if ( key != 'class' ) {
            String methodName = "set${key.capitalize()}";
            WebSession.metaClass[key]."${methodName}" = { -> delegate
                System.out.println("Setting key: ${key}");
                webSession[key] = delegate;
            }
        }

    }
```

Also, I don't know if looping over the property names minus 'class' is hacky and there's a better way to get the declared fields.

Comment: Generally you should avoid side effects for getters/setters like that.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, because it's deceiving about what it's doing, especially if you're using the shorthand like webSesssion.firstName = 'John'... you don't want to deceive developers who assume it's only setting a field.  But in this case it's a special class that we know is always going to be persisted to the session and/or cache, and we want that to automatically happen without having to write a lot of plumbing code to do the same thing on every setter.

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept all the getters and setters by implementing `void setProperty(String, Object)` and `Object getProperty(String)`. Here's an example:

## Example

```
def a = new WebSessionDecorator(new WebSession())

a.firstName = 'John'

println a.firstName

class WebSession {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email
}

class WebSessionDecorator {
    private WebSession delegate

    WebSessionDecorator(WebSession webSession) {
        this.delegate = webSession
    }

    void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
        println "LOG: Setting $name to $value"
        delegate.setProperty(name, value)        
    }

    def getProperty(String name) {
        println "LOG: Returning $name"
        delegate.getProperty(name)
    }
}
```

### Output

The output looks like this:

```
LOG: Setting firstName to John
LOG: Returning firstName
John
```

### Explanation

The `WebSessionDecorator` intercepts all property access, providing an opportunity for going whatever you want to do. Then, it delegates the property access to the actual `WebSession`.

I chose to go with a decorator in order to avoid recurring calls to `getProperty()` and `setProperty()`, and to make it possible to use the decorator only when applicable. For example, you may not want to use it in a unit test.

Comment: It is worth noting that using `setProperty()` and `getProperty()` will override the use case where it looks like you set the attribute directly (e.g. `webSession.firstName = ...`), but this will not work with the generated setters and getters, such as `webSession.setFirstName()`, so just beware that you don't expect it to work in both cases.

Comment: Ah... so that explains it. Thanks mnd!

Comment: Thanks... This didn't work for me, because I'm looking for the IDE (IntelliJ) to know what the properties are on WebSession (to find references etc).  My goal is to get better representation of what's used where with the tools.  I ended up getting something to work where I define setProperty method in the WebSession class, and inside that it does extra stuff + this.@"$name" = value (to avoid recursion), got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075348/groovy-how-to-set-a-property-within-setproperty-and-avoid-infinite-recursion